# Bash to print a Nth word if an specific string exists

Tags: linux, bash

In IHS access log I need to grab a info line by line iff there is a 401 response.

The following is the format and I need to go through the log **line by line** to grab a specific number in front of the user property (which in this example is 123 or 432) only when there is 401 response found on the line.

something like, if nth word of the line is 401 the from the nth column grab the number and print it.

```
 myhost.com xxx.x.xxx.x aaa.aa.aa.aaa - - [14/Aug/2013:10:44:55 +1000] "GET /http/user=123 HTTP/1.1" 401 55 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)" 21293 80 0
 myhost.com xxx.x.xxx.x aaa.aa.aa.aaa - - [14/Aug/2013:10:45:55 +1000] "GET /http/user=432 HTTP/1.1" 401 55 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)" 21293 80 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokenize the record by whitespace or '=' sign and print the 10th field if the 12th field is 401.

```
awk -F' |=' '$12 ~/401/{print $10}' inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F'\s|=' -lane 'print $F[9] if $F[11] == 401' your_file.txt
```